# How to hide the tab close button [X] in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext, close-button

I open a lot of tabs in sublime, when I switch tab by clicking other tab, I sometimes mis-click on their close button.

Is it possible to hide the close button(X) in sublime? I usually close with keyboard shortcut or middle click, so I don't need the close button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in preference:

"show_tab_close_buttons": false